# How can i scroll a specific scroll bar with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrollbar

I tried to scroll a scroll bar and it worked, but there are two scroll bars and the code is scrolling the wrong one. How can i scroll a specific scroll bar?

```
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 200)") #the code i used
```

The scrollbar i try to scroll is here:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CLMCNSenf-E/
after u press on the "liked persons" spot, u will see a small window with a scroll bar popping in the middle of ur browser.

Comment: The element having the bar you wish to scroll would have an Id you must select for instead of using window object. If not you have to set the id so you can use it.

Comment: @Atmas thats sounds like it would work, but i cant find an id in the code for the scroll bar. Any idea?

Comment: It would help if you could share the url of the website you're trying to scrape, so the issue can be visualized

Comment: @twiddler, yes for sure.  I edited the question, now u can exactly see what i mean.

Comment: You can actually scroll those elements into view . The div seems to be uninteractable.